# Put latest data from table into a text field inside a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to put the latest data in my database into one of the textfield in my form. How can I do it. Any advice?

I have a form that needs the final text field to have the latest data from a table in my database. Some of the form in my table is dynamic but I don't know how to put the latest data into the final text field.

Comment: What do you mean by *latest*?  Tables are inherently *unordered*, so unless you store with each record some indicator of when it was inserted, how do you determine which record is the latest one?

Comment: uhmm order by id no based on primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code and table structure its hard to suggest something. But still you can do something like

```
$query = "select * from users order by id desc limit 1";
```

The table structure for users is

```
---------------------
   id   |   username
---------------------
    1   |   test
    2   |   new_user
```

So in this case "new_user" row will be returned when you run the query

Comment: If you're assuming that there is a column called `id`, why not assume that there is one called  `insertion_time` (the former requires a further caveat that it strictly increases monotonically with time, whereas the latter ought to be self-evident)?

Comment: @eggyal : You are correct. I thought of that, but as beginners generally dont tend to have that field so gave other way even if they dont have the `insertion_time` column in their table. But you are correct.

Comment: tnx all of you guys are helpfull and respond quickly xD

Comment: @Justin Capuno Cuizon : If you think the answer helped you mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Make a query that fetch your table ordered DESC by id and limit 1

Get the result and Print it in the textfield

I think you just need a way to do it not coding since it a basic query

I hope this can help :)

Comment: You assume that there is an `id` column, and that it strictly increases monotonically with time.

Comment: yes I assumed that :), it's not given from the question but if it's not there this is a good guideline

Comment: @JustinCapunoCuizon if that helped and you are done accept an answer :)